# Call certain method based of condition

Tags: java, repeat

I recently wrote this piece of code:

```
  public Object getProperty(String key) {
    if (this.plugin.getConfig().isBoolean(key)) {
      return this.plugin.getConfig().getBoolean(key);
    } else if (this.plugin.getConfig().isColor(key)) {
      return this.plugin.getConfig().getColor(key);
    } else if (this.plugin.getConfig().isConfigurationSection(key)) {
      return this.plugin.getConfig().getConfigurationSection(key);
    } else if (this.plugin.getConfig().isDouble(key)) {
      return this.plugin.getConfig().getDouble(key);
    } else if (this.plugin.getConfig().isInt(key)) {
      return this.plugin.getConfig().getInt(key);
    } else if (this.plugin.getConfig().isItemStack(key)) {
      return this.plugin.getConfig().getItemStack(key);
    } else if (this.plugin.getConfig().isList(key)) {
      return this.plugin.getConfig().getList(key);
    } else if (this.plugin.getConfig().isLong(key)) {
      return this.plugin.getConfig().getLong(key);
    } else if (this.plugin.getConfig().isOfflinePlayer(key)) {
      return this.plugin.getConfig().getOfflinePlayer(key);
    } else if (this.plugin.getConfig().isPrimitiveWrapper(key)) {
      return this.plugin.getConfig().getPrimitiveWrapper(key);
    } else if (this.plugin.getConfig().isSet(key)) {
      return this.plugin.getConfig().getSet(key);
    } else if (this.plugin.getConfig().isString(key)) {
      return this.plugin.getConfig().getString(key);
    } else if (this.plugin.getConfig().isVector(key)) {
      return this.plugin.getConfig().getVector(key);
    }
  }
```

As you can see, it is super repetitive and very ugly.

Is there a better way it can be written?

---

`plugin.getConfig()` returns [one of these](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/configuration/file/FileConfiguration.html). I want to make a method that, when given a path (`key`) which points at some value in a YAML file, I can return that value no matter what its type is.

Comment: Not without reflection or modifying the source for the type returned by `getConfig()`.

Comment: Java y u do dis

Comment: How do you expect your client to behave? Presumably they now have to do `if (getProperty("key") instanceof Integer) {...}`. Just expose methods that get the key as the expected type.

Comment: Don't blame Java for your poor design.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes, that's what the client would do

Comment: @shmosel what's a better way to do it then?

Comment: I can't tell you without more context. Show us the config class. Show or explain how this method is used.

Comment: @shmosel `plugin.getConfig()` returns [one of these](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/configuration/file/FileConfiguration.html). I want to make a method that, when given a path (`key`) which points at some value in a YAML file, I can return that value no matter what its type is.

Comment: You mean like [`get(key)`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/configuration/ConfigurationSection.html#get(java.lang.String))?

Comment: @shmosel yeah, didn't know it existed

Comment: do accept the answer so that others can benefit from what you went through

Comment: @MozenRath the accepted answer helps me, but it doesn't really answer the firsts question I posed - what's standard practice?

Comment: the standard practice is dependent on the type of client for this code. If the client will directly use the various types of properties by casting them to the actual classes, then you expose the different methods from `ConfigurationSection`. however, if the immediate client is simply going to pass the properties on to other classes, then its best to expose just the single method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of all of this mumbo jumbo, why don't you simply write this:

```
public Object getProperty(String key) {
    return this.plugin.getConfig().get(key);
}
```

This is especially because you are in the end returning just an `Object`. So better return what you get from the YAML.

If you do want to make your client's life easy, try exposing the methods of `ConfigurationSection`  individually rather than combine them.

The standard practice here, is dependent on the type of client for this code. If the client will directly use the various types of properties by casting them to the actual classes, then you expose the different methods from `ConfigurationSection`. however, if the immediate client is simply going to pass the properties on to other classes, then its best to expose just the single method